# "Field 'COUNT(id)' has no dataset" TSQLQuery in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, dbexpress

Sorry for my english, but i hope you'll understand me :P

I'm trying to create new TSQLQuery component in code, without placing it on form. I wrote that code:

```
var
sql:tsqlquery;
pole:TFMTBCDField;

....
   sql:=tsqlquery.Create(self);
   sql.SQLConnection:=ddm.konekszyn;
   sql.SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(idrap) FROM raporty WHERE idkier="'+lvkierowcy.Selected.Caption+'";';
   pole:=TFMTBCDField.Create(self);
   pole.Name:='sqlilerap';
   pole.FieldName:='COUNT(idrap)';
   pole.FieldKind:=fkData;
   pole.DisplayLabel:='COUNT(idrap)';

   sql.Fields.Add(pole);
   sql.Open;
   showmessage(sql.FieldByName('COUNT(idrap)').AsString);
   sql.Free;
   pole.Free;
```

but i'm getting exception when i try to access data:

```
First chance exception at $75999617. Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Field 'COUNT(idrap)' has no dataset'. Process htstrm2.exe (2308)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Can you just clarify - are you getting that at the point you open the query, or at the point at which you're trying to read the contents of the new field? Does it barf at 'SQL.Open' or at the 'ShowMessage' line?

Comment: ok - as a matter of interest, what happens if you change 'FieldByName('cnt').AsString' to 'Fields[0].AsString' - same error?

Comment: change your sql query to "SELECT COUNT(idrap) AS A FROM ".and use FieldByName('A') or Fields[0] . use parameterized query instead of string concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even make a field.  Queries such as this return one and only one field.  So just reference from the fields array:

```
var
sql:tsqlquery;

....
   sql:=tsqlquery.Create(self);
   sql.SQLConnection:=ddm.konekszyn;
   sql.SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(idrap) FROM raporty WHERE idkier="'+lvkierowcy.Selected.Caption+'";';
   sql.Open;
   showmessage(sql.fields[0].AsString);
   sql.Free;
```

Comment: Thanks, it just works :D didnt know that i dont have to add fields. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your database driver reports the empty field name for the aggregate expression.

Alias your field:

```
   sql:=tsqlquery.Create(self);
   sql.SQLConnection:=ddm.konekszyn;
   sql.SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(idrap) AS cnt FROM raporty WHERE idkier="'+lvkierowcy.Selected.Caption+'";';
   pole:=TFMTBCDField.Create(self);
   pole.Name:='sqlilerap';
   pole.FieldName:='cnt';
   pole.FieldKind:=fkData;
   pole.DisplayLabel:='cnt';

   sql.Fields.Add(pole);
   sql.Open;
   showmessage(sql.FieldByName('cnt').AsString);
   sql.Free;
   pole.Free;
```

Comment: nope, didnt help. Still error:

First chance exception at $75999617. Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Field 'cnt' has no dataset'. Process htstrm2.exe (2864)

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly assign the dataset to the field, try adding this line

```
pole.DataSet:=sql;
```

Bye.

Comment: you must change the field type from TFMTBCDField to TIntegerField

Answer (score 0):

Alias the column being returned. You can then access it by that aliased name:

```
sql.SQL.Text:='SELECT COUNT(idrap) AS iDrapCount FROM raporty WHERE dkier 
="'+lvkierowcy.Selected.Caption+'";';
....
pole.FieldName := 'iDrapCount';
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does "isn't helping" mean? Are you getting an error message? Is your computer throwing up it's hands and saying "No way I'm helping you"? Providing nothing useful means that's what you get for help - nothing useful.

Comment: inst helping in this case means that nothing changes after making an alias, still same error

Comment: Can you single step through the code in the debugger and show exactly which line is causing the exception?

Comment: showmessage(sql.FieldByName('COUNT(idrap)').AsString); here is a problem, but now its solved, as M Schenkel written above, a field isnt required. Thanks for trying to help. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line to your query:

```
AND idrap <> nil
```

Comment: but, its not a query problem (i think), query executed in phpmyadmin works without problems, and returns values between 2 and 16.

Comment: I think that some values of idrap in your dataset might be nil. Some database engines won't do aggregates if all values upon which aggregates are calculated are not <> nil.

Comment: it didnt help. idrap is a primary key column in table so it cant be nil (null?), it always have a value.

Comment: Did you traverse the dataset with sql.First, sql.Next
? You just executed the query.